# Inner join on fields with different domains

Tags: abap, opensql

I have a query which looks a bit like this:

```
 SELECT a~matnr AS material,
        b~aedat AS date,
        SUM( c~ormng ) AS dummy
    INTO TABLE @gt_dummy
    FROM ekpo AS a
    INNER JOIN ekko AS b
      ON b~ebeln = a~ebeln
    INNER JOIN lips AS c
      ON c~vgbel = a~ebeln
      AND c~vgpos = a~ebelp
    INNER JOIN likp AS d
      ON d~vbeln = c~vbeln
    WHERE a~matnr IN @gr_dummy1
      AND a~werks IN @gr_dummy2
    GROUP BY a~matnr, b~aedat
    ORDER BY a~matnr, b~aedat.
```

It's not going to work because `LIPS-VGPOS` and `EKPO-EBELP` have different domains so '00010' in `EBELP` would be '000010' in `VGPOS`. An alternative to this would be to just get the EKPO data, use a conversion exit function and then use a `FOR ALL ENTRIES` query to get the LIPS entries. Then since you can't use `SUM` and `GROUP BY` with `FOR ALL ENTRIES` I would need to do the summations manually.

Of course it's not a huge amount of work to do all this but I'm interested if there's a quicker way to do this e.g. in a single query? Thanks.

EDIT: We're on 7.40

Comment: You may use functions since 7.40, like `SUBSTRING`, but I can answer precisely only if you indicate your ABAP version.

Comment: @SandraRossi We're on 7.40. I should have mentioned this.

Comment: In this situation `ON concat( '0', a~ebelp ) = c~vgpos` would also work, but I think it's also from the 7.50. There are couple of demo programs like DEMO_SQL_FUNCTION_CONCAT, DEMO_SQL_FUNCTION_STRING which shows possibilities of the SQL string functions but maybe they "comes" with 7.50

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I only see two possibilities before ABAP 7.50:

- `FOR ALL ENTRIES` as you suggested
- Execute "native" SQL directly on the database connected to your ABAP software. This can be done with `EXEC SQL` or ADBC (class `CL_SQL_STATEMENT` and so on), or AMDP if your database is HANA.

Answer (score 1):

It's not your version but for ABAP >= 7.50, there are SQL string functions LIKE for instance `SUBSTRING`:

```
 SELECT a~ebeln, a~ebelp, c~vbeln, c~posnr
    FROM ekpo AS a
    INNER JOIN lips AS c
      ON c~vgbel = a~ebeln
      AND substring( c~vgpos, 2, 5 ) = a~ebelp
    INTO TABLE @DATA(gt_dummy).
```

Comment: I copy/pasted your 7.40 code and I'm getting: "The function "SUBSTRING" is unknown." Is it definitely available in 7.40?

Comment: Sorry, no. I didn't check that... It appeared in 7.50. Let me find another solution. I forgot to mention that I don't have a 7.40 system to check the solution (only 7.52). Answer edited, that may help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

If you have at least ehp5 on 7.40, you can use CDS views in a workaround for FOR ALL ENTRIES with SUM.

1. Join `EKKO` and `EKPO` in OpenSQL
2. Create a CDS view on `LIPS` using fields `VGBEL, VGPOS, SUM(ORMNG)`, with `GROUP BY` on the first two
3. Call this CDS view with FOR ALL ENTRIES